# Issue when scrolling down the ion-option list, on scrolling up and down it selects the checkbox

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I m using `ion-select` and `ion-option` to display some content in the alert controller.

It has a type multiple so that multiple options can be selected using a checkbox.But the problem is in case of iphone as its touch is too sensitive, while scrolling up and down it takes the click event and selects/unselects the checkboxes.

I m very new to ionic and can not figure out the solution for it.
I just want the checkbox to take the click rather then the entire item having label and checkbox.
This is the code i m currently using:

```
 <div *ngIf="field.xtype==='multiselect'" [hidden]="field.hide">
    <ion-item style="margin-left:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
    <ion-label style="margin-bottom:10px; font-size:15px;" color="basic" stacked>{{field.label}}</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]='field.value' multiple="true" name="field.name" (ionChange)=getSublistdetails(field.name,field.value)>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let option of field.options" input type="checkbox">{{option.text}}</ion-option>
   </ion-select>
   </ion-item>
 </div>
```

I have spent almost two days in searching a solution for it, but no success yet.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks